# phonegap app in not uploaded in ios store

Tags: ios, cordova, webview, app-store, phonegap

**Dear Developer,
We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "Saudi Freelancer" 1.0 (1.0.6). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).**

**Getting this error while uploading in the app store.**

App is build in phonegap and just opened the website url in the application.
These are the plugin used in the app.

```
cordova-plugin-audioinput 0.3.0 "Audio Input"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.4-dev "Device"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
cordova-sms-plugin 1.0.0 "Cordova SMS Plugin"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

So how to solve this error and upload the application in app store.

Comment: The App Store will no longer accept new apps using UIWebView as of April 2020

Comment: so what I need to do ?

Answer (score 2):

Phonegap build is discontinued
https://blog.phonegap.com/update-for-customers-using-phonegap-and-phonegap-build-cc701c77502c

Old answer:

It's a known Phonegap Build issue, they have not updated cordova-ios to 5.1.1, required to hide the UIWebView code from Apple review.
So you should switch to another service or build locally with a mac.

Comment: Also note that Cordova-ios 6.0.0 is out and auto includes wkwebview by default but some plugin (splashscreen) is not compatible yet, also XHR is not working yet.

Comment: so I can't use 6.0.0 version also because of splash screen and some other issue. So what's the solution for it ?

Comment: you can't use 5.1.1 nor 6.0.0 because phonegap build doesn't support any of them, you have to build locally or use a different cloud service

Comment: is it possible in ionic ?

Comment: Yes, there is a guide for some things you might need to do https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/cookbook/phonegap-build-migration